# labels for checkboxes with the same name

Tags: html, checkbox

I'm writing a small application in which users are able to define popups on a map by selecting from a list of checkboxes. Each checkbox corresponds to a specific data value, and the list is generated dynamically.

As I get the data, I loop through it and build a list in the following format:

```
<label>
    <input type='checkbox' name='enabled_data', value='DATA VALUE' />
    DATA VALUE
</label>
```

When the form is submitted, I get an array of enabled_data items, which I can then work with.

However, as soon as I try to attach a for value to the labels, the labels stop working - probably because each checkbox shares the same name.

```
<label for='enabled_data'>
```

I imagine I'll end up with tens of these checkboxes per map, and am wondering if the only way to do this is to generate some sort of unique id for each checkbox (e.g. map name + data_value) to get the labels to properly work?

Comment: Why do you need the for attribute, if you are wrapping the label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide an id for `for` attribute value.

> for = string:
>   Specified to indicate a form control with which the caption is to be associated.
>   The attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable form-associated element in the same Document as the label element.

See **[doc](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label)**

it stopped working because there is no element with id `enabled_data`. specify an id for your `inputs` and provide that as the `for` attribute value for your respective label.

```
<label for="check1">DATA VALUE</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='enabled_data' value='DATA VALUE' id="check1" />
```

Also you have a comma between 2 attributes.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='enabled_data', value='DATA VALUE' />
                                          ^___________________
```

Comment: Ah, sorry about the comma - I've been writing everything in Jade and the comma syntax is specific to it.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` that you see points to the Element ID, not the name.

```
<label for="element_id">
```

Take a look here at [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp).